# how to install ubuntu 18.04 alongside with windows 10 with mbr disk partition

Tags: system-installation, mbr

tried to install ubuntu 18.04 alongside with windows 10 but i can't make disk partition that recognized by ubuntu when i tried to make the installation, I tried through windows and also through ubuntu installation please help me what to do I check the disk partition and show that is MBR so please advise what to do to install ubuntu alongside windows 10.

Comment: It's unclear please provide more details.

Comment: I tried to install ubuntu from my windows 10 I have a 1TB of hard drive I tried to make disk partition I did but when i tried to installed ubuntu the system not recognized the previous OS that i had install already in my laptop.

Comment: Did you try to install Ubuntu in the same disk where windows 10 is present? Or else did you install Ubuntu on a separate disk? Is it a desktop or laptop? How many disks are present in your system?

Answer (score 0):

First and Foremost, BACKUP YOUR WINDOWS DATA!

The second thing you need to do is get a 4GB thumbdrive to install the linux iso file onto. Be sure to make it bootable. See https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-windows#0 for more details on how to do that.

Once you have your thumbdrive all ready to go, reboot your computer. At the very start of the reboot process, you'll have to press the hotkey for boot options. This varies depending on your system. Esc, F9, F11 are all options that I've seen. Once the boot menu appears, select your USB thumbdrive and boot into the live Ubuntu system that runs off of your thumbdrive.

One of the shortcuts on the desktop will be to install Ubuntu. Select this and follow the onscreen prompts. When you get to part on where to install Ubuntu, it will give you the option of installing Ubuntu with Windows. It will shrink the windows partition if needed and install Ubuntu. I recommend having a separate hard drive, but if you don't have one and can't shell out $40-$50 for a hard drive then  one drive will work.

Just keep on following the prompts and you should be fine.